# What's the proper way to compare locations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have followed single object that represents location from CSV and JSON:

```
 "value_location1": {
  "json_lat": "-118.3844000",
  "csv_lat": "-118.3844"
   },
  "value_location2": {
  "json_lat": "-117.933122",
  "csv_lat": "-117.933122"
},
```

Actually i have array of **145k (importent)** of these objects and I need find good way to make `value_location.csv_lat` and `value_location.json_lat` to be equal.

As you see `json_lat` provides `-118.3844000` when `csv_lat` - `-118.3844`.

Both have the same value as <kbd>double</kbd> but not as <kbd>String</kbd>,

What should be, high performance, way to do that?

Comment: `parseFloat(string).toFixed(4)`

Comment: `Both have the same value as double but not as String` -> according to your javascript object that doesn't seem to be the case at all. The 2 properties are defined as strings. So you're gonna have to parse those strings to actual floating point numbers (`parseFloat`) and then round the results (`.toFixed`)

Comment: Note that with `toFixed()`, you will also end up with a string, not a floating point number.

Comment: @adeneo, i added other object, I know its good way but i dont want to cut off to 4 digits after dot. sometimes I can get lat or long 5-8 digits after dot and i run in loop on all 145k objects. Thanks

Comment: @Lepidosteus - there's always `(string*1000) / 1000` to solve that. And parseFloat would normally remove the zeros anyway.

Comment: @adeneo: I didn't point it as an issue, but as a note to be aware of. Given the OP comments, he doesn't fully realize the difference between a number, and a string representation of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pasre values to floats and compare float values
Or you might get into this issue [Javascript: Comparing two float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343623/javascript-comparing-two-float-values)

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to turn these strings into floating point numbers ? Then use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and you can then compare them as floats ([be aware of the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values?rq=1))

```
value_location.csv_lat = parseFloat(value_location.csv_lat, 10);
// value_location.json_lat is the number -118.3844
value_location.json_lat = parseFloat(value_location.json_lat, 10);
// value_location.csv_lat is the number -118.3844
```

Are you trying to remove the extra 0 at the end of the strings, no matter how many digits there is after the colon ? If so, just convert them back to string after parseFloat()

```
value_location.csv_lat = parseFloat(value_location.csv_lat, 10) + '';
// value_location.json_lat is the string "-118.3844"
value_location.json_lat = parseFloat(value_location.json_lat, 10) + '';
// value_location.csv_lat is the string "-118.3844"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this:

> I need find good way to make value_location.csv_lat and value_location.json_lat to be equal.

Then `value_location.csv_lat = value_location.json_lat` will work a treat.

Comment: json object returns `csv_lat` and `json_lat` as strings and `-118.3844000 != -118.3844`

Comment: @MaximShoustin but what do you actually want? If you want to make them the same, then just copy one value to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters JavaScript only has the `number` data type. But if you want these two numbers to equal the same `string` use the `toFixed()` method to get the amount of decimal points you want. Like this:

```
var example_number = 5.333000;
var rounded_number = example_number.toFixed(2);
alert(rounded_number);
```