# javascript operators do not match the input decimalx

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't understand why when I use the condition value like `a > b` but it doesn't work properly, maybe because of the value a = decimal. following my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="numberdays"  id="numberdays" value="10.0/>
<input type="text" name="cutii" id="cutii" value="9.0">
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" id="subcut" type="submit" disabled>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
cutifrom.addEventListener('input',()=>{
            if (cutii.value > numberdays.value) {
            subcut.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }else{
            subcut.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        }
        }) ;
```

the result is that my button is disabled, it shouldn't be.

here's my js. actually number days I use the datepicker and generate numbers that are automatically generated. maybe because it's the condition that I use the operator is not detected.
***JS for datepicker***

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

    let $fromDate = $('#fromdate'),
        $toDate = $('#todate');

    $fromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
    });

    $toDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());
    });;
});

      $(function() {
    let $fromDate = $('#fromdate'),
        $toDate = $('#todate'),
        $numberDays = $('#numberdays'),
        $numberCuti = $('#cuti');

    $fromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());

        $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($toDate.val(), $(this).val()));
    });

    $toDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());

        $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($(this).val(), $fromDate.val()));
    });

   cutifrom.addEventListener('input',()=>{
        if (parseFloat(cuti.value) >= parseFloat(numberdays.value)) {
        subcut.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }else{
        subcut.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
    }) ;     
        
function calculateDateDiff(endDate, startDate) {
        if (endDate && startDate) {
            let e = moment(endDate),
                s = moment(startDate);

            return e.diff(s, "days");
        }

        return null;
    }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690070/javascript-float-comparison

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+compare+numbers+from+inputs) of [Using Javascript to compare two input numbers in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15914514/4642212). Also read [Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27849944/4642212) and [Javascript to convert string to number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130454/4642212).

Comment: what if the value of  ```numberdays``` is automatically input from js datepicker ?

Comment: if i input manual in ```numberdays``` its working . but if I'm using datepicker for value on my ```numberdays``` its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript float comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690070/javascript-float-comparison)

Answer (score 3):

Your value is a String type and the comparison is not like Number, try converting the value to a number and see if it works.

You need to change the code to this form:

```
  cutifrom.addEventListener('input',()=>{
        if (Number(cutii.value) > Number(numberdays.value)) {
        subcut.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }else{
        subcut.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
    }) ;
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: can you show me how to do it ? I'm sorry I new in js :')

Comment: Try printing to the log the selected entry what datepicker is and see how it can be accessed accurately.

Comment: i don't know what you say, im sorry. where I get it ?

Comment: Add this line at the beginning of the function:
console.log ('numberdays.value: ',numberdays.value) and check with the developer tools in the console what the value is written there, by this you will know where the error is.

Comment: it looks like i have a problem in my datepicker js. When I input and look at the console, nothing happens. the result is NULL

Comment: I have added it to my question above.